# Python adding text at the line

Tags: python, file

I have a file which contains following row:

```
//hva_SaastonJakaumanMuutos/printData/reallocationAssignment/changeUser/firstName>
```

I want to add "John" at the end of line.

I have written following code but for some reason it is not working,

```
def add_text_to_file(self, file, rowTitle, inputText):
    f = open("check_files/"+file+".txt", "r")
    fileList = list(f)
    f.close()

    j = 0
    for row in fileList :
        if fileList[j].find(rowTitle) > 0 :
            fileList[j]=fileList[j].replace("\n","")+inputText+"\n"
            break
        j = j+1

    f = open("check_files/"+file+".txt", "w")
    f.writelines(fileList)
    f.close()
```

Do you see where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are you getting an error? (Are you on windows?)

Comment: I am not getting any error, I have written this script and providing it argument from app model, it just does not write "John" at the end of first name ! this is how I send arguments to add value to txt file "xml/Jonathan/First name"

Comment: What's the value of `rawTitle`? Are you on windows? Why don't you use `.strip` instead of `.replace`? Is there a particular reson for not using a xml parser?

Comment: well I was following another example from net and there it never saves the file @Rik Poggi

Comment: @plaes: Emh... To save a file in Python you just need to write to it.

Comment: @Shaheryar: Please [edit] the question and provide the additional info there. It's hard to understand them from comment.

Comment: @RikPoggi Duh.. I missed the `writelines` call. Thanks

Comment: @Rik Poggi value for rowTitle is "John"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving much informations, so even thoug I wouldn't use the following code (because I'm sure there are better ways) it might help to clear your problem.

```
import os.path

def add_text_to_file(self, filename, row_title, input_text):
    # filename should have the .txt extension in it
    filepath = os.path.join("check_files", filename)
    with open(filepath, "r") as f:
        content = f.readlines()

    for j in len(content):
        if row_title in content[j]:
            content[j] = content[j].strip() + input_text + "\n"
            break

    with open(filepath, "w") as f:
        f.writelines(content)
```

Comment: Rik what else Information is needed,  rowTitle is Name of Person such as "john" and inputText is "fistName" and john should be added at the end of firstName, LIne is file "xml" is as follow  //hva_SaastonJakaumanMuutos/printData/reallocationAssignment/changeUser/firstName>

Comment: @Shaheryar: Then you need to write before the `>` not before the end of the line. But it would be better to use a xml parser to modify an attribute, as I already  suggested you. There are a couple in the stdlib and lxml or beautifulsoup are other ones. And for the third time: Are you on windows?

Comment: Hey Thanks to every one there was no problem in my code only thing is I have changes the position of arguments and everything is Fixed but I appreciate ur response keep the good work going on, peace

Answer (score 1):

`str.find` may return `0` if the text you are searching is found at the beginning. After all, it returns the index the match begins.

So your condition should be:

```
if fileList[j].find(rowTitle) >= 0 :
```

**Edit:**

The correction above would save the day but it's better if you things the *right* way, the pythonic way.

- If you are looking for a substring in a text, you can use the `foo in bar` comparison. It will be `True` if `foo` can be found in `bar` and `False` otherwise.
- You rarely need a counter in Python. `enumerate` built-in is your friend here.
- You can combine the iteration and writing and eliminate an unnecessary step.
- `strip` or [`rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) is better than replace in your case.
- For Python 2.6+, it is better to use `with` statement when dealing with files. It will deal with the closing of the file right way. For Python 2.5, you need `from __future__ import with_statement`
- Refer to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for commonly preferred naming conventions.

Here is a cleaned up version:

```
def add_text_to_file(self, file, row_title, input_text):
    with open("check_files/" + file + ".txt", "r") as infile:
        file_list = infile.readlines()

    with open("check_files/" + file + ".txt", "w") as outfile:
        for row in file_list:
            if row_title in row:
                row = row.rstrip() + input_text + "\n"
            outfile.write(row)
```

Comment: No it shouldn't - it should be `rowTitle in fileList[j]`. This ain't C or C++ or Java.

Comment: so my condition if fileList[j].find(rowTitle) > 0  is ok?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Fair enough. I was going to edit for a few style suggestions anyway.

Comment: @Shaheryar: only if you meant `rowTitle in fileList and not fileList.startswith(rowTitle)` - i.e. it's in there but not at the start of the line. My suggestion is just stylistic.

Comment: Hey Thanks to every one there was no problem in my code only thing is I have changes the position of arguments and everything is Fixed but I appreciate ur response keep the good work going on, peace @ChrisMorgan

Comment: how come my reputation goes down to 19 from 23?